# Python script to split multi page PDF works with some PDFs and not Others

Tags: python, pdf

I am using the following script in Windows to split multipage PDFs. The script looks like this...

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("*pathToPDF**”, "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

I am replacing *pathToPDF* with the path to the multipage PDF to be split on the fly.

I got it working fine with a nine page 91kb PDF, but when I tried it with a 232 page 1.62gb PDF it throws the following error...

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   “C:\MySplitFolder\splitPDFwindows.py”, line 3, in  inputpdf =
>   PdfFileReader(open(“C:\MySplitFolder\1973PB1PhyOfficeParkingBldg_CD.pdf”,
>   “rb”)) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
>   ‘C:\MySplitFolder\x01973PB1PhyOfficeParkingBldg_CD.pdf’

Here is the line 3 code of the small pdf...

```
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("C:\MySplitFolder\BestInCategory_JR 2.pdf", "rb"))
```

Here is the line 3 code of the large pdf...

```
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("C:\MySplitFolder\1973PB1PhyOfficeParkingBldg_CD.pdf", "rb"))
```

The document name is the only difference between the 2 scripts when executed. While the error speaks of an invalid argument, I do not see any difference between the 2 lines except for the document name. Is the a file size problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you provided is `C:\MySplitFolder\1973PB1PhyOfficeParking`, but the error message is showing the path `C:\MySplitFolder\x01973PB1PhyOfficeParking`. **Notice the extra `x0`** after the second `\` !

Python is assuming that `\` is an *escape character* and is treating `\197` as escape sequence, replacing it with the equivalent ASCII character.

To fix this, tell python to treat the path as a **raw string**, by **prefixing it with an `r`**:

```
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(r"C:\MySplitFolder\1973PB1PhyOfficeParkingBldg_CD.pdf", "rb"))
```

The reason the first file worked is because, in python, "all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged". So, both `\M` and `\B` are unrecognized and kept unchanged. Hence, resulting in a path string that is accidentally correct!

Comment: Perfect. I put the r in and that fixed the problem. Thank you!